# I want to return a sublist of object and Total size of the Original List

Tags: c#, java, jakarta-ee

I want to return a sublist of object and Total size of the Original List.

in this case  can i use MAP .

Example :-

```
Map<Integer,String> sample(){
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(0);

for(i=0;i<50;i++)
list.add(i+"");

List<String> sublist = list.sublist(0,10);
Integer totalsize = list.size();
Map<Integer,String> map = new Hashmap<Integer,List>(0);
map.put(totalsize,sublist);
return map;
}
```

otherwise can i return one POJO Object fro returning these information to calling function.

I need a performance wise guidance on this .

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Use a POJO, you can always add more fields to it in future, if required.

Comment: What language in here? C# or JAVA?

Comment: return a map containing both the size and list !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Map to store the sublist and size of the original list with two different keys, here is the code in java to meet the req...

```
Map<Integer, String> sample() {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(0);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        list.add(i + "");

    List<String> sublist = list.subList(0, 10);
    Integer totalsize = list.size();

    map.put("sublist", sublist);
    map.put("original_list_length", totalsize);

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C#, you can use the `ArraySegment<T>` structure. It contains a reference of the original array too. You can find the details here in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/1hsbd92d.aspx)